# Excel Conditional Formating only formatting top cell in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to use conditional formatting to highlight which of the cells in a row are today's date. I am using the formula:

=G2=(TODAY()) and the range is Sheet1!$G$2:$G$10.

However only the first cell in a column is highlighted even when the same date is listed below.

On a very similar formatting formula (=E2="High" on the range E2:E10) the formula seems to work a treat! I can't work out why there is a difference.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Are the entries in G2:G10 just dates? If there are times, too then they won't exactly match today

Comment: I no longer have the issue as using the provided date formulas where you select from drop-downs still seems to work but would still be interested to see a solution

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=G2=TODAY()
```

(but only because one set of parentheses is not required!) and for Applies to:

```
 =$G$2:$G$10
```

The Applies to range has to be in the same sheet as is G2 in your formula.

I suspect if you go back to the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager you will see that what you entered was automatially removed (substituted by `=$G$2`, hence the one cell that 'works').

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, neither seemed to help unfortunately :(